# Fullscreen window breaks other windows' resolution

Tags: 20.04, fullscreen

I am playing Minecraft fullscreen on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Whenever I do Alt-Tab to another program (like nautilus, firefox, ...) it only renders 1/4th of the program's window.

Is this a bug and/or how do I fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to Minecraft causing your resulution to be set to a lower resolution. If you then switch to other windows, you indeed see them enlarged and only a part of it. Not a bug, but this is how Minecraft interacts with your resolution.

Resolution:

*Possibility 1* - not recommended:  decrease your desktop resolution until it matches the resolution of Minecraft when full screen

*Possibility 2*: Do not switch windows while in full-screen Minecraft, or run Minecraft in a normal window.

*Possibility 3*:File an issue with Minecraft and hope the developers will accommodate for higher screen resolutions.

Comment: I just switched to PopOS and it works just fine! Thanks for the response, though.